# format as a percent on a datarow

Tags: vb.net, datatable, string.format

I've been at this for an hour, but I can't seem to format a string as a percent while I am looping through a datatable.  Any ideas?  The string value that is being passed in is "3.22"

```
    Public Function securityDt() As DataTable

    Dim secMasterDt As New clsDataSecurity
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    dt = secMasterDt.getSecurityMasters()

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim divYieldColumn As String
        divYieldColumn = String.Format("{0:p}", row("dividend_yield"))
        row("dividend_yield") = divYieldColumn
    Next

    Return dt

End Function
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

"P" = default 2 decimal places

"P1" = 1 decimal place.

```
row("dividend_yield") = Convert.ToDouble(row("dividend_yield")).ToString("P1",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

hopefully this helps.

Comment: I haven't got it to work yet, but I will continue to work with your code for awhile.